# @Url.Action showing unnecessary parameter value after rendering page in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, url.action

Why @Url.Action generates browser's URL on a tag?
My local browser URL is
http://localhost:26377/Users/details/1

I want to remove unnecessary parameter which is autogenerated from @Url.Action.
My code is

```
<a href="@Url.Action("details", "Users")" class="btn btn-light  add-new">Add</a>
```

and after rendering page it shows

```
<a href="/Users/details/1" class="btn btn-light  add-new">Add</a>
```

Expected result:

```
<a href="/Users/details" class="btn btn-light  add-new">Add</a>
```

Comment: I assume that the method that generated that view (where your `<a .. >` element is has an `int id` parameter and that you passed it a value of `1`

Comment: Can you provide the `Details` method in `Users` controller? I think the problem comes from `[Route]` attribute.

Comment: This is controller
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
 

            return View();
        }

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right: `int id = 0`

Comment: So what is resolution for the same? MVC is totally new for me.

Comment: You would be getting that result if the `{id}` segment is not marked as optional. You can solve it by making it optional, or by using `@Url.Action("details", "Users", new { id = "" })`

Comment: Thank you so much @TânNguyễn for your valuable help

Comment: Thank you so much @StephenMuecke for your valuable help. I preferred this @Url.Action("details", "Users", new { id = "" }) and my code works properly.